# Overflow not working without static width

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, overflow

I'm trying to write a table component and I want it to scroll if it doesn't fit on the screen, but overflow doesn't work. It only works if you set the width of the element to the string. If the component does not fit into col, then it throws it somewhere

Component code:

```
export const DataTable = (props: { header: [String], fields: [[String]] }) => {
    return (
        <div className="datatable">
            <div className="datatable-header p-2">
                <button aria-label="Clear" type="button" className="button">
                    <TbFilterOff></TbFilterOff>
                    <span>Clear</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="datatable-wrapper">
                <table className="datatable-content">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {props.header.map((item) => (
                                <th>
                                    <div className="datatable-header-content">
                                        {item}
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {props.fields.map((field) => (
                        <tr>
                            {field.map((item) => (
                                <td>
                                    {item}
                                </td>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CSS:

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.datatable {
    position: relative;
}

.datatable-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}

.datatable-content {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.datatable-content > thead > tr {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.datatable-header-content {
    width: 13rem;
    height: 4rem;
}
```